# Function for connecting to mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, function, pdo

I made my first function for connecting to mysql database. I have index.php and functions.php and i included functions.php to index.php!
 This is my Connect to database function...

```
function connect_to_database()
{

/*** mysql hostname ***/
$hostname = 'localhost';

/*** mysql username ***/
$username = 'root';

/*** mysql password ***/
$password = '';

try {
$dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=zadatak1", $username, $password);
/*** echo a message saying we have connected ***/
/**echo 'Connected to database';**/
}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
echo $e->getMessage();
}
return $dhb;

}
```

I don't know is it correct and if i am calling it right.

I type in index.php

```
<?php

require_once 'functions.php';

connect_to_database();

active_links();

include 'includes/head.php';

include 'includes/nav.php';
```

..................

Comment: `$DB = connect_to_database(); $DB->function();`

Comment: This is merely something for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Notice: Undefined variable: dhb in C:\xampp\htdocs\senso_zadatak\functions.php on line 24

Fatal error: Call to a member function function() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\senso_zadatak\index.php on line 5

it isnt working

Comment: `return $dbh;` not `return $dhb;`

Comment: You have a typo. You say $dbh earlier in the function and then try to return $dhb at the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it works fine now, here is the answer! Thank you for help

I created file named config.php

```
// PDO connect *********
function connect() 
{
    $host = 'localhost';
    $db_name = 'database_name';
    $db_user = 'root';
    $db_password = '';
    return new PDO('mysql:host='.$host.';dbname='.$db_name, $db_user, $db_password, array(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION, PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8"));
}
```

and just calling connect function like this, $pdo = connect();  or any name for var but that is the way!

```
<?php

include 'config.php';

$pdo = connect();

........
```

Answer (score 0):

See comments:

```
function connect_to_database()
{

   /*** mysql hostname ***/
   $hostname = 'localhost';

   /*** mysql username ***/
   $username = 'root';

   /*** mysql password ***/
   $password = '';

   $dbh = false; // initialized for error

   try {
      $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=zadatak1", 
                    $username, $password);
      /*** echo a message saying we have connected ***/
      /**echo 'Connected to database';**/
   }
   catch(PDOException $e)
   {
       echo $e->getMessage();
       // consider to exit / throw own exception / stop continuing script anyhow ....
   }

   // returns false on error
   return $dbh; // typo here, was $dhb !!  
}
```

Usage:

```
$DB = connect_to_database(); 

if ( $DB !== false )
    $DB->function();
```